# Новые товары не отображаются в магазине

Tags: php, magento

Добрый день.

Возникла проблема. При добавлении новых товаров они не отображаются в указанных категориях (вообще не видно на сайте), хотя если перейти по адресу, то они видны, правда, не в категории:

[image]

Подскажите, в чем может быть беда?

Comment: А в бд они есть, посмотри в таблицах связаны по айди с категориями?

И такой вопрос, индексацию делал?

Comment: > Подскажите, в чем может быть беда?

я думаю проблема в том, что она не в категории. Возможно, категории не проставились?